# how to insert php variable into description of atribute tag

Tags: php, html

Hi I am trying to add function of dynamic deleting rows list and want to name id's of html tags using php code, do you have any ideas how to insert php code into  description of tag atributes properly(the code is in while loop [it must help me to delete selected rows from list dynamicly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjSf4.png)), thanks.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "guest_book");
$query ="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY ID DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Datatables Jquery Plugin with Php MySql and Bootstrap</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<br /><br />
<div class="container">
    <h3 align="center">Datatables Jquery Plugin with Php MySql and Bootstrap</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="employee_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Browser name</td>
                <td>Designation</td>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td>Remove</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
            $id = 1;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $but_id = "but"."$id";
                $row_id = 'row'."$id";
                echo ' 
                              <div id = "$row"> // this line <?php ?> dont help

                               <tr>  
                                    <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["browser_name"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["ip"].'</td>  
                                    <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>  
                                    <td><button type="button" name="remove" id ="$id" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td>// this line 
                               </tr>  
                               </div>

                                                              ';

                ++$id;
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#employee_data').DataTable();
        $('.btn').click(function(){
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            alert(button_id);
            $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're putting the whole string in single quotes you have to concatenate the value:

```
echo ' 
      <div id = "'.$row['id'].'">
```